# Microsoft Volume Licences - How do I get and use them?

Tags: microsoft-office-2016

First off, I apologize if this is the wrong *fault section for this question.

I'm in a small shop with 13 computers. 12 are running Windows 7 Pro (until they fix roaming profile start menus) and one is running Server 2012r2 (2016 once it comes out). We need 12 copies of Microsoft Office Professional. The average cost per copy is $400 on newegg since we need Access.

I'm trying to understand how volume licencing works. I'm a pirate turned IT Admin so this whole legitimate thing is new to me. If I wanted to get 12 licences for 12 computers that will be used by an unknown number of people, how would I do that. Also can I put SQL Server 2016 and eventually Server 2016 on it and if so how.

My final question is, would I be better off just buying the copies from Newegg instead and forget about using Volume Licencing all together?

What would cost the least?

I feel like VL is more for businesses having more systems than licences where less than every system is in use. So any help would be great.

Edit:

You know, marking this as a duplicate once was enough. Hitting me four times is just rude. I can't make comments anymore. This just discourages new people from asking questions. Also, the listed article was just as helpful as the listed answer. The real answer to those who are viewing this question is simple.

Don't ask for Volume License related question on Stack. Call your Microsoft License Dealer in your local area. You'll avoid a reputation beat down and get a real answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **Microsoft Volume Licences - How do I get and use them?**
>
> I'm trying to understand how volume licencing works.

I suggest having a look at [What is Microsoft Volume Licensing?](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/licensing/licensing-programs/how-volume-licensing-works.aspx) to get started.

> ### [What is Microsoft Volume Licensing?](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/licensing/licensing-programs/how-volume-licensing-works.aspx)
>
> Microsoft volume licensing is an easy and affordable way to run
>   Microsoft software across multiple computers and use Online Services
>   across multiple users within an organization.
>
> **How does Volume Licensing Work?**
>
> By acquiring licenses through Microsoft Volume Licensing programs, you
>   pay only for the software license. Eliminating the physical costs of
>   boxed software and purchasing in volume often reduces cost and
>   provides more customized purchasing options and improved software
>   management.
>
> Simply stated, volume licensing makes it easier and more affordable to
>   run software across multiple computers and use Online Services across
>   multiple users within an organization.
>
> In the case of some Microsoft Volume Licensing programs, you may also
>   purchase Software Assurance. This comprehensive maintenance offering
>   can help you get the most out of your software investment. It combines
>   the latest software with phone support, partner services, training,
>   and IT tools. You can choose Software Assurance at the time of
>   purchase and begin using your benefits immediately for the term of
>   your license agreement.
>
> ### Keys to understanding Microsoft Volume Licensing
>
> To choose the optimal approach for your organization, you must first 
>   understand the major characteristics of Volume Licensing policies and 
>   programs.
>
> Areas for consideration include:
>
> - The size and type of your organization.
> - The products that you want to license.
> - The way in which you want to use those products.
>
> Microsoft tailors some of its programs to meet the needs of specific          > industries, such as public sec industries, such as public sector organizations > like schools and universities, depending on the primary function of the
>   organization.
>
> For smaller organizations, the Open Programs provide a simple, cost-effective
>   way to acquire the latest Microsoft technology.
>
> [Learn more Download the Microsoft Volume Licensing reference guide (PDF, 1 MB)](http://download.microsoft.com/download/a/7/0/a70853c1-a783-4d48-a7ad-f404abdb1e7d/Microsoft_Volume_Licensing_Reference_Guide.pdf)
>
> [Get the latest updates from the Volume Licensing team blog](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/volume-licensing/)
>
> <sub>[source](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/licensing/licensing-programs/how-volume-licensing-works.aspx)</sub>

---

### You ask. . .

> What would cost the least?

I suggest having a look at [How to purchase through Volume Licensing](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/Licensing/how-to-buy/how-to-buy.aspx) and potentially making a phone call to ask questions.

> ### [How to purchase through Volume Licensing](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/Licensing/how-to-buy/how-to-buy.aspx)
>
> Are you ready to buy, or just looking for pricing information? An authorized 
>   Microsoft Partner can help.
>
> [Find a Microsoft Partner to get pricing and purchasing details](http://pinpoint.microsoft.com/companies/search/b1?fs=100010&wt.mc_id=Deeplink_USLicense_Home_2_LicenseSpecilization&q)
>
> Or call to find a Microsoft Partner in your region:
>
> - In the United States, call (800) 426-9400.
> - In Canada, call the Microsoft Resource Centre at (877) 568-2495.
> - Worldwide, find information about availability in your area on the [Microsoft Volume Licensing website](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/Licensing/worldwide.aspx) for your country/region.
>
> Research Volume Licensing
>   options Before you buy, use the tools and resources here to learn more
>   about licensing and financing options for Microsoft Volume Licensing.
>
> **Get an estimated quote:** [Microsoft License Advisor](http://mla.microsoft.com/default.aspx)
>
> **Need payment flexibility?:** [Microsoft Payment Solutions](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/Licensing/how-to-buy/financing.aspx)
>
> **Purchase Online Services:** [Online Services](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/Licensing/product-licensing/online-services.aspx)
>
> <sub>[source](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/Licensing/how-to-buy/how-to-buy.aspx)</sub>